# How can I convert a string to a float and always show 2 decimal places?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, floating-point

I've managed to get 2dp format for a number, however, it returns a string. Is there any way to keep float and always have 2dp regardless if there are instances of .00?

```
average = "{:.2f}".format(10.0)
print(average)
```

Outputs

```
'10.00'
```

However, if I try to convert this to a float using the following

```
average = float("{:.2f}".format(10.0))
```

It outputs the following float:

```
10.0
```

I've seen other threads that say to use Decimal, but i'm uncertain of how to do this without importing library.

Is there anyway to achieve this without importing any libraries?

Comment: Why can't you just keep it as a float and then print when you need to?

Answer (score 1):

Keep it as a float the entire time, at the last step when you want to show it covert it to string with two decimal points. This is not the perfect answer but it will work.